# Grafana dashboard: Db query error: sql: expected 30 arguments, got 0

Tags: sql, sql-server, grafana, grafana-variable

I have a constant variable `Shift1_StartTime` whose value is '7:30:00'
and I have a SQL query

```
WITH DataLogKWH AS (
    SELECT
        SourceID,
        TimestampUTC,
        Value - LAG(value, 1, 0) OVER (PARTITION BY SourceID ORDER BY TimestampUTC) AS actual_value
    FROM [ION_Data].[dbo].[vDataLogKWH]
)
SELECT SUM(actual_value)
FROM DataLogKWH
WHERE SourceID IN (${Compressors})
AND TimestampUTC >= CAST(CAST(DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AS DATETIME) + CAST(${Shift1_StartTime} AS TIME)
```

Here is my variable

[image]

and here is my SQL query in Grafana screenshot

[image]

however I try use `Shift1_StartTime` variable in this query, this gives me an error:

> Db query error: sql: expected 30 arguments, got 0

Need help please. Thanks .

Comment: that what i am not able to understand how can it expect 30 parameter, if i remove this part ' + CAST(${Shift1_StartTime} AS TIME)' then query run fine. there is some problem with incoperating custom varibale in sql query

Comment: in general, i want to setup custom time variable having value like '7:30:00' which can be changed occasionally based on requirement. i want to use that variable in the sql query to filter data.

Comment: let me know what are the things i need to provide for more clarity

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256417/discussion-between-jitender-singh-and-dale-k).

Comment: Well as I posted in my answer, your SQL as it stands is invalid, so the first thing you need to do is correct your SQL. Once your SQL is correct you can work out the Grafana error.

Comment: Perhaps Grafana has been talking to ChatGPT and is hallucinating error messages? If you execute your example T-SQL with appropriate variable replacements you get the error, `Msg 402 Level 16 State 1 Line 11 The data types datetime and time are incompatible in the add operator.`